Docker compose enter debug mode upon breakpoint while dropping stdout from web server
Have a question on using docker-compose when entering into debug mode by manually setting breakpoint().
This is my service and it has a /health which calls almost every 5s, and it prints out 200 status code to stdout.
However, when using docker attach <container_id> to enter into the container, as it hits a breakpoint, it is interlaced with the (pdb) debugger.
Is there a way to redirect these stdout from /health temporarily to not "bother" the debugger session?

